# Listing values of unknown enum

Tags: java, class, enums

Say we have a `Class` object. Name it `cls`.

Now `cls.isEnum()` returns `true`

What a joy!!! Could I please have the values listed to me? (one sugar, no milk)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

getEnumConstants() a method of the Class object returns an array of Objects

```
public static enum E {
    A, B, C, D;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class c = E.class;
    for(Object b:c.getEnumConstants())
    {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Prints:

> A
>   B
>   C
>   D

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`EnumSet.allOf(Class<E>)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf%28java.lang.Class%29), where `<E extends Enum<E>>`

Given:

```
public static enum Alphabet {
    A, B, C, D;
}
```

You can write:

```
    for (Enum<?> e : EnumSet.allOf(Alphabet.class)) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    // A, B, C, D
```

Comment: I can not use it without access to Alphabet. Say there's Class cls = Alphabet.class and work only with cls.

Comment: @Joel: getting around the generic type check is tricky (I don't think there's a typesafe way of doing it if you start with a `Class<?>`), but I'm not sure what you're saying. This definitely works, but `Class.getEnumConstants()` is best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I looked at it, learned from it and marked it useful. As you suggest, I accepted the getEnumConstants() answer. The main reason for it is that it requires nothing other then the Class object itself.

Answer (score 2):

The following main:

public class GetEnumFields {

```
public static enum Enum {

    A, B, C, D;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Enum a = Enum.A;
    Field[] declaredFields = a.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < declaredFields.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(declaredFields[i]);
    }
}
```

}

prints:

```
public static final GetEnumFields$Enum GetEnumFields$Enum.A
public static final GetEnumFields$Enum GetEnumFields$Enum.B
public static final GetEnumFields$Enum GetEnumFields$Enum.C
public static final GetEnumFields$Enum GetEnumFields$Enum.D
private static final GetEnumFields$Enum[] GetEnumFields$Enum.ENUM$VALUES
```